# "text-decoration: none" not working, even with "!important"

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

When I try to use something like `underline` it works, but `none` does not, even with `!important`. Does anyone know why?

PS: The *del* element should stay with the line, I'm trying to remove the line from this new after content.

```css
del:after {
  content: attr(datetime);
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<del datetime="2001-01-01">Text</del>
```

Comment: TEXT2001-01-01 is result where TEXT is a *del element* and 2001-01-01 is a pseudo element.. this question is not a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the `<del>` element itself rather than the `:after` pseudo element.

** Edit **

Updated upon further instruction. This code will remove the text-decoration from the pseudo, but not the rest. The key was adding `display: inline-block;`.

```css
del:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(datetime);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<del datetime="2001-01-01">Text</del>
```

Comment: But I want just the date without the line. The rest should stay with the line.

Comment: Yeah, but I tought would be a simple-correct-css-way to do it, not using span, because using it I have to use <span> all the sentence and use `del span { text-decoration: line-though }` after using `text-decoration: none`. Sounds stupid.

Comment: @Hugo apologies, I was mistaken. I'll update my example shortly.

Comment: @Hugo updated the answer, although I'm not entirely sure why the `display: inline-block;` is necessary in this instance.